# Bash EOF block in EOF block possible?

Tags: bash, eof, heredoc

I'm trying to write in a file a block containing its own EOF block. Is it something doable in bash?

```
cat > terragrunt.hcl <<'EOF' 
# Automatically generated from script $(basename $0)

# Generate the AWS provider block
generate "provider" {
  path      = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents  = <<EOF
# Terragrunt root config
provider "aws" {
  # Only these AWS Account IDs may be operated on by this template
  allowed_account_ids = ["${local.account_id}"]
  region = "${local.infra_region}"
  version = "${local.customer_vars.locals.aws_provider_version}"
}
EOF
}

# Automatically generated from script $(basename $0)
EOF
```

As expected it is failing with:

```
❯ ./example.sh 
./example.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./example.sh: line 17: `}'
```

What is the best solution to deal with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are calling an "EOF block" is actually called a ["Here Document"](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) (commonly abbreviated "heredoc"), and the string "EOF" can actually be any "word" you like.

The heredoc contains everything up to its matching delimiter, so nesting two heredocs is just a case of picking two different delimiters:

```
cat > terragrunt.hcl <<'ENDTERRAGRUNT' 
# Automatically generated from script $(basename $0)

# Generate the AWS provider block
generate "provider" {
  path      = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents  = <<ENDROOTCONFIG
# Terragrunt root config
provider "aws" {
  # Only these AWS Account IDs may be operated on by this template
  allowed_account_ids = ["${local.account_id}"]
  region = "${local.infra_region}"
  version = "${local.customer_vars.locals.aws_provider_version}"
}
ENDROOTCONFIG
}

# Automatically generated from script $(basename $0)
ENDTERRAGRUNT
```